# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Это мой код

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import scale
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('wine.data.txt', names = ['Class', 'Alcohol',
 'Malic acid',
 'Ash',
 'Alcalinity of ash', 'Magnesium', 'Total phenols', 'Flavanoids', 'Nonflavanoid phenols', 'Proanthocyanins', 'Color intensity', 'Hue','OD280/OD315 of diluted wines', 'Proline'])
X = data.values[::, 1:14]
y = data.loc[:,'Class']

kf = KFold(n_splits = 5, shuffle = True, random_state = 42)

scores = list()
for k in range(1, 51):
    clf = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = k)
    scores.append(cross_val_score(clf, X, y, scoring = 'accuracy', cv = kf).mean())
scores2 = pd.Series(scores, index = range(1,51))

scl = pd.Dataframe(data = scale(X))
scl.to_excel('pandas.xlsx')
```

Появляется такая ошибка

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'Dataframe'

Хотя на Series не ругается

Comment: замените: `pd.Dataframe` --> `pd.DataFrame`

Comment: спасибо большое